# quickly access models attributes via foreign key relationship in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, jinja2

I have a model where one field is a ForeignKey so that each child object is linked to a parent object.

In my (jinja2) templates, I list some attributes from a subset of objects from the child model, including one of the parents' attributes. The page loads very slowly, so I am wondering if there is a faster way to do the following:

views.py

```py
class TransactionView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Transactions
    context_object_name = 'transaction_list'
    template_name = 'bank/transactions.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Transactions.objects.filter(owner_id=self.request.user)
```

template.html

```html
            <tbody>
              {% for transaction in transaction_list %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{transaction.source_document.service_provider}}</td>
                  <td>{{transaction.account}}</td>
                  <td>{{transaction.tnsx_date}}</td>
                  <td>{{transaction.end_bal}}</td>
                  <td>{{transaction.amount}}</td>
                  <td>{{transaction.category}}</td>
                </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
```

models.py

```py
class Transactions(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.tnsx_uuid)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_index=True,
        editable=True,
    )
    source_document = models.ForeignKey(
        Document,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=True,
    )
    tnsx_uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    account = IBANField(enforce_database_constraint=True)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=False, null=False)
    currency_assumed = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    <etc>
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/optimization/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As iklinac suggested, using `.prefetch_related()` increases the speed of the query dramatically.

change `views.py` to the following:

```py
class TransactionView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Transactions
    context_object_name = 'transaction_list'
    template_name = 'bank/transactions.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Transactions.objects.filter(owner_id=self.request.user).prefetch_related('source_document')
```